# package org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, dependencies

I have this dependency failing while trying to setup a legacy project in my local setup -

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project project-name: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/sandeepan.nath/path/to/project/common/throttlectrl/rule/ComparatorFactory.java:[12,32] package org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sandeepan.nath/Users/sandeepan.nath/path/to/project/common/throttlectrl/rule/ComparatorFactory.java:[42,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable StringUtils
[ERROR]   location: class com.path.to.class.ComparatorFactory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I could not pinpoint any maven repository for this. I found a java class in -

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.hibernate/hibernate-tools/5.2.8.Final/source-code/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x/StringUtils.java

I tried to get a jar for this but could not find. I found this java library however. What is the best way for me to resolve this dependency?

Thanks. If I need to prepare a jar file using this, by what name do I prepare the jar file, class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the jar with 'org/hibernate/tool/hbm2x' package by adding this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.ga</version>
</dependency>
```